# Separate rows in a 2d array into two new arrays based on the ending substring in a particular column

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, filtering, grouping

I'm trying to seprate rows in the following multidimentional array by the ending substring in a soecific column.

```
$objects = [
    (object) [
        'term_id' => 5,
        'name' => 'Freelance',
        'slug' => 'freelance-category1',
        'count' => 0
    ],
    (object) [
        'term_id' => 2,
        'name' => 'Full Time',
        'slug' => 'full-time-category2',
        'count' => 0
    ],
    (object) [
        'term_id' => 6,
        'name' => 'Internship',
        'slug' => 'internship-category1',
        'count' => 0
    ],
    (object) [
        'term_id' => 3,
        'name' => 'Parta Time',
        'slug' => 'part-time-category2',
        'count' => 0
    ],
    (object) [
        'term_id' => 4,
        'name' => 'Temporary',
        'slug' => 'temporary-category1',
        'count' => 0
    ]
];
```

I want to populate two new arrays with `category1` and `category2` rows. Qualifying rows should be determined by the substring after the last hyphen in the slug value.

Comment: try a `foreach` and `explode`

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing fancy to advise here.  Just iterate the array of objects, isolate the target substring in the slug value, then route any qualifying objects to their respective new group.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/sLicK))

```
$cat1 = [];
$cat2 = [];

foreach ($objects as $object) {
    if ($dash = strrpos($object->slug, '-')) {  // don't need to check for false-vs-0 due to task logic
        $cat = substr($object->slug, ++$dash);  // or $dash + 1 ...same thing
        if ($cat == 'category1') {
            $cat1[] = $object;
        } elseif ($cat == 'category2') {
            $cat2[] = $object;
        }
    }
}
echo "Category1 : ";
var_export($cat1);
echo "\n---\n";
echo "Category2 : ";
var_export($cat2);
```

Output:

```
Category1 : array (
  0 => 
  (object) array(
     'term_id' => 5,
     'name' => 'Freelance',
     'slug' => 'freelance-category1',
     'term_group' => 0,
     'term_taxonomy_id' => 5,
     'taxonomy' => 'job_listing_type',
     'description' => NULL,
     'parent' => 0,
     'count' => 0,
  ),
  1 => 
  (object) array(
     'term_id' => 6,
     'name' => 'Internship',
     'slug' => 'internship-category1',
     'term_group' => 0,
     'term_taxonomy_id' => 6,
     'taxonomy' => 'job_listing_type',
     'description' => NULL,
     'parent' => 0,
     'count' => 0,
  ),
  2 => 
  (object) array(
     'term_id' => 4,
     'name' => 'Temporary',
     'slug' => 'temporary-category1',
     'term_group' => 0,
     'term_taxonomy_id' => 4,
     'taxonomy' => 'job_listing_type',
     'description' => NULL,
     'parent' => 0,
     'count' => 0,
  ),
)
---
Category2 : array (
  0 => 
  (object) array(
     'term_id' => 2,
     'name' => 'Full Time',
     'slug' => 'full-time-category2',
     'term_group' => 0,
     'term_taxonomy_id' => 2,
     'taxonomy' => 'job_listing_type',
     'description' => NULL,
     'parent' => 0,
     'count' => 0,
  ),
  1 => 
  (object) array(
     'term_id' => 3,
     'name' => 'Parta Time',
     'slug' => 'part-time-category2',
     'term_group' => 0,
     'term_taxonomy_id' => 3,
     'taxonomy' => 'job_listing_type',
     'description' => NULL,
     'parent' => 0,
     'count' => 0,
  ),
)
```